# Is logical locking still needed when writing STM software?

Tags: stm

I didn't write anything STM (Software Transactional Memory) -related, only read the information on the web. So here is just an imaginary example

Assume we have a FIFO buffer with a maximum allowed items in it. So we fill the array until the maximum items reached and shift it when no more items left. With traditional approach, I'd lock not only actual shifting and appending, but also the conditional read that checks whether the maximum is reached. I must do this otherwise two threads can decide simulatingly that the only item left is intended for them. So I have a kind of logical lock here not related directly to writing conflict.

With STM I suppose two threads can both decide the item is left and try to fill the last item. But the correctness is kept since a rollback is fired in one thread (or both) after detecing that another thread modified the same memory. Optimistic scenario says that some time one of the threads would finally increase the number of elements and another one would finally go other branch (FIFO shifting). But I also see a possibility of an indifinite loop here if both keep noticing the final item is left and trying to fill it.

So do I still need to add "logical" locks when writing STM-related software?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need any logical locking - certainly not for this scenario.

It is not possible for two threads to "keep noticing" that one slot is still free. The only way for one thread to get rolled back is if another thread has successfully committed - meaning that the last slot has been filled.

Deadlock is guaranteed to never happen because locking happens only during the commit phase, and by then we know exactly what to lock, and can take locks in a consistent order. Livelock is guaranteed to never happen because one transaction can only ever rolled back because another transaction committed successfully. It is therefore impossible for two transactions to block each other forever.

What *is* theoretically possible is starvation. One particularly unlucky transaction could be rolled back infinity times. This can only happen if an infinite number of conflicting transactions are committing successfully. So globally, the system must make progress, but locally, one specific transaction can get stuck.

In practice, the only way this is likely to happen is if you're running an infinite stream of short transactions, and then you start one very long transaction which thus never gets to complete.

Comment: MVCC databases like MySQL and PostgreSQL still suffer from deadlocks and you still have to understand locking semantics when using them in highly complex concurrent scenarios. I thought STM derived its ideas from database transactions such as MVCC. Why does STM not suffer from the same problems?

Comment: 1. The current STM implementation doesn't use multi-version concurrency; it uses optimistic locking. 2. I can't speak about MySQL, but I was under the impression PostgreSQL never deadlocks. At worst, your transaction gets rolled back with "snapshot too old", or with write conflicts.